# How to create a child iteration using TFS API?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have to create a child iteration in Team Foundation Server 2017 (on premise). In my current Visual Studio project I am using then NuGet packages "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client" and "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client". None of the APIs offer a method to create a child iteration. I also didn't find any documentation on how to achieve this task. Anyone out there who knows how to create a child iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use below sample to create a child iteration using the TFS API:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server;
using System;

namespace _AddIteration
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string iterationName = "TestIteration";
            string collection = @"http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection";
            var tfsServer = new Uri(collection);
            var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsServer);
            tpc.Authenticate();
            var css = tpc.GetService<ICommonStructureService>();
            string rootNodePath = string.Format("\\{0}\\Iteration", "ProjectName");
            var pathRoot = css.GetNodeFromPath(rootNodePath);
            css.CreateNode(iterationName, pathRoot.Uri);

        }
    }
}
```